# Integral of $\ln (3x) / x$

Tags: integration, logarithms

I believe this should be a simple problem but I don't have an answer key to confirm if this is right, and some of the similar questions I can find online seem to be giving more complicated solutions.

The problem is:
$$ \int \frac{\ln (3x)}{x} \, dx $$

And this is my solution, based on the fact that $ \int \ln(ax) \, dx = \frac{1}{x} $:

$$ u = \ln(3x) $$
$$ \implies \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} $$
$$ \implies du = \frac{1}{x} dx $$
So:
$$ \int \frac{\ln (3x)}{x} dx = \int u \, du$$
$$ \implies  \frac{u^2}{2} + C$$
$$ \implies  \frac{(\ln (3x))^2}{2} + C$$

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$

Comment: Yes it is correct. A quick check is to take the derivative of your answer and see you get the expression inside the integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to check the result. Since
$$\int\frac{\ln(3x)}{x}dx=\frac{(\ln(3x))^2}{2}+C$$
then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(\ln(3x))^2}{2}+C$$
should be the initial function. Hence, doing the differentiation 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(3x))^2&=\ln(3x)\frac{d}{dx}\ln(3x)\\
&=\ln(3x)\cdot\frac{1}{3x}\cdot 3\\
&=\frac{\ln(3x)}{x}.
\end{align}
This is your initial function, and hence your integration was correct.